# Ubuntu 12.10 freeze in the Ubuntu logo

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot

I have brought a new computer with No Operating System with the intention of installing Ubuntu 12.10 and quite excited about it.

New computer is a Zoostorm AMD A4 3300 Dual Core

Despite trying with both a bootable USB and a DVD with Ubuntu 12.10 on them, the computer will ask if I want to install or try it then when I click on install it freezes and does nothing more on a black screen or the purple screen which merely shows "Ubuntu".

When I try to install a Windows 7 Pro from DVD it has no problems.

I am suspecting a clash with hardware but any ideas would be welcome as I really do want to use Ubuntu and not Windows 7 on this machine and brought for the sole purpose of this.

Comment: Here is some info about Boot options which let you choose. for example try to add vga=768 and acpi=off at boot options and then boot your linux [Ubuntu boot options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) [Ubuntu RadeonHD Community ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonHD)

Comment: In the bios settings maby search after secure boot and disable this.

Comment: Can you boot a live system with *"Try Ubuntu"*?

Comment: Well, not sure what I have done but I read on here somewhere and someone suggested (to another problem) pressing F6 and disabling a Nomodost (or something like that).  Seems to be working now, although one of the scripts that was running said unable to do something.

Comment: Well, scrub that!!  It looked liked it was installing but when I rebooted it booted to a black screen and wouldn't proceed!!!  Any ideas?

Comment: Try installing Ubuntu 13.04 (pre-release) from here http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/
It works a lot better than 12.10.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get Ubuntu onto this machine (and my machine is exactly the same specs as above and I was having exactly the same issue) the following guide will help solve the problem:

[Live CD won't boot on Lenovo ThinkPad E525](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68750/live-cd-wont-boot-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e525/70302#70302)

Once you have installed the alternate install 11.10, it will get stuck whilst starting up, at which point press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> taking you to the TTY console.

At this point you'll need to type the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Once that is finished, reboot the machine (easiest way is to type):

```
sudo reboot
```

When Ubuntu starts you might have a greyed box in the bottom right hand corner that says "AMD Unsupported Hardware", simply use the following guide to resolve that:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1904997

From this point I upgraded Ubuntu, since 11.10 is no longer supported (Ubuntu will tell you this), to 12.04. I will probably follow the upgrade path to 13.04 at some stage, but for now, I have a working Ubuntu installation on the machine.